# Debug assertion failed opencv xmemory0 C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to run the code from [calibration](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d94/tutorial_camera_calibration.html), and i'm stuck with this error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program:
C:\Users\openCV\Desktop\Git\AzTest\Debug\AzTest.exe
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0
Line: 94

Expression: "_Count <= (size_t)(-1) / _Sz" && 0

For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

To be honest I don't know what else should I do, or why is this error happening.

What is to be noted is that the code used to **work** on the **same** PC.

I've modified the code (when it worked, and it worked after I done the changes), code can be found [here](https://link.removed) (The project is there, also it is configured for having the `OpenCV` directory on `C:\opencv`.

Comment: [link to snippet](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v9aQ5.png)

Comment: The assertion contain the "&& 0" which is the same as "false" -- so the assertion is always false -- that sounds like intentional, and you will have to get the original author of the code to look at the problem, or look at the surround code parts yourself.

Comment: @Soren, the problem is that I even reinstalled windows, visual & openCV, thus the problem it is still there. What bothers me even more, is that it worked.

Comment: You don't have sufficient information to diagnose the problem -- the surrounding code to the assert will have to be posted in the question as a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of digging I found the answer. It was a miss configuration imported from another project.
*Project properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies:
`opencv_ts300d.lib;opencv_world300d.lib;`; (the right way for opencv3). 
Mine was:
`opencv_ts300d.lib;opencv_world300.lib;`
Afterwards I get intro "missing MSVCR120D.dll", I fixed that by changing the opencv version to OpenCV310.
Tried to fix that missing dll problem by uninstalling and reinstalling all the redistributable that I could find on Microsoft website.

Also if you will have "opencv_world310d.dll" missing, just copy&paste it into the project release/debug folder.